# Why is the checkbox filtering not working in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, filtering, checkboxlist

Been trying for 8 hours now to get this to work and still no luck. Ultimately, what I am trying to do is print a loop which shows all items by default. Then when a user selects a checkbox it will filter out those items where they are set to false.

I have the following group of checkboxes and a loop:

```
  <div class="container" id="clubs">
    <div class="filter">
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="All" /> All</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="ClubParking" /> Parking</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="ClubToilets" /> Toilets</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="ClubFloodlights" /> Floodlights</label>
    </div>

    <ul class="clubs-list">
        <li v-for="club in filteredClubs">{{ club.clubName }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then in my application I have the following code

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el:  "#clubs",
    data: {
        clubs: [
            { clubName: "Club One", clubParking: true, clubToilets: false, clubFloodlights: true },
            { clubName: "Club Two", clubParking: true, clubToilets: false, clubFloodlights: false },
            { clubName: "Club Three", clubParking: false, clubToilets: true, clubFloodlights: true },
        ],
        selectedCategory: "All"
    },
    computed: {
        filteredClubs: function() {
            var vm = this;
            var category = vm.selectedCategory;

            if(category === "All") {
                return vm.clubs;
            } else {

         return vm.clubs.filter(function(club) {
            return selectedFieldNames.every(fname=>club[fname])
             const selectedFieldNames =  selectedCategory.map(category=>{
                  switch(category){
                     case 'Toilets':
                      return 'clubToilets';
                     case 'Parking':
                      return 'clubParking';
                     case 'Floodlights':
                      return 'clubFloodlights';
                  }
            })

        });

            }
        }
    }
});
```

I have even made a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vwBMoe) I am better with a working modal then I can backtrack to see why I have been going wrong. Any help welcome as I have'nt left the house all day trying to get it to work.

Comment: 1. `return selectedFieldNames` works before your map/switch

Comment: 2. You should use radio instead of checkbox if using `string` as `selectedCategory` OR `selectedCategory` should be array if using checkbox

Comment: Radio boxes will mean a user can only select one option and not multiple options. For example they want to see clubs which have parking and floodlights. Therefore, I need to use checkboxes. As for the rest, I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: As I said, you need to use array to save values of checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Edited your codepen as discussed on comments above.
 1. moved from "string" selectedCategory to "array"
 2. changed filtering to work for array

```js
var vm = new Vue({
 el:  "#clubs",
 data: {
  clubs: [
   { clubName: "Club One", clubParking: true, clubToilets: false, clubFloodlights: true },
   { clubName: "Club Two", clubParking: true, clubToilets: false, clubFloodlights: false },
   { clubName: "Club Three", clubParking: false, clubToilets: true, clubFloodlights: true },
  ],
  selectedCategories: ["All"]
 },
 computed: {
  filteredClubs: function() {
   if (this.selectedCategories.includes('All')) {
    return this.clubs;
   } else {
        return this.clubs.filter(club => {
          return this.selectedCategories.some(category => club[category])
        })
   }
  }
 }
});
```

```css
.container {
 padding: 20px;
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

label {
 display: block;
 line-height: 1.5em;
}

ul {
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

li {
 padding: 8px 16px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="clubs">
 <div class="filter">
  <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategories" value="All" /> All</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategories" value="clubParking" /> Parking</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategories" value="clubToilets" /> Toilets</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategories" value="clubFloodlights" /> Floodlights</label>
 </div>
 
 <ul class="clubs-list">
  <li v-for="club in filteredClubs">{{ club.clubName }}</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```